# How to refresh page/popup content when a popup is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify, store

I have had a huge issue lately with trying to get a photo gallery to work within a popup. I have posted a question about this issues before at the following link but no one has been able to help solve the issue.

https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Discussion/Why-does-this-code-fail-to-work-when-being-called...

Please checkout the link to get a good understanding about what problem I have.

So to begin, I am using a google photos embed that is connected to a google photos album. I plan to use this for all my products and allow people to submit there own images of the product and have those images added to the photo gallery for other customers to see. Only issue is that the google photos embed doesn't work correctly. As shown in my previous question the google photos embed when opened in the popup is broken and the only time the popup works is when I quickly open the popup "before the page has finished loading". Below are example images of how the popup functions.

[Popup before being opened...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISBMK.jpg)

[Popup opened but not working...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUpxM.png)

[Popup opened and working (only when opened fast before page finished loading)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myqrL.jpg)

Although this is true once I close the popup and open it again the popup is broken again. This has lead me to then know that I should be able to make this popup photo gallery work if everything is completely refreshed on command of someone opening the popup and have everything refreshed without closing the popup.

Below are the codes used for my popup... I am using magnific popup made by Dmitry Semenov

html popup button code

```html
<a class="btn size-chart-open-popup" href="#Image-Gallery">See Image Gallery</a>


<div id="Image-Gallery" class="mfp-hide">

  <div class="row">
  <div class="gallerycolumn"></div>
  <div class="gallerycolumn"></div>
</div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="galleryleft" style="background-color:#000000;"> 
      



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/publicalbum@latest/embed-ui.min.js" async></script>
<div class="pa-carousel-widget" style="width:100%; height:480px; display:none;"
  data-link="https://photos.app.goo.gl/fdDmX5CQnCpPkrm98"
  data-title="Greek Key Ring"
  data-description="13 new photos added to shared album">
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/0qLN_Xu5BgFic25TVrUA-SVNOFM6QW2llhbiLySb7bbWTs-3pYwZi0OLelVcj17qr6rHlUn1Rt4e4f3sT5g3mZjqu2j2ta2waz2LUL9Nu9s7RURpREMbmDiYMb6u6kUMKwWq7i6VNA=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/zSn5SD3eiBIVbFoWnIYJfythDg-YdqvZRwUcKCO_0A5jerwYWUf2QvP0IANQwpUt75xLWiWw6Is8uiIDmwD_y6tXPs7aSaMCfcZSOCVP-PtkZoQbDugp7AszENZyN--c3wBhGO7pjA=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Y7lISOdW_2v6VKE0F_XebMEUk8NHwxbP9tn1tJ8p7BcJ__EY0MnN0D_lETofiawnbCwkashQfYzsamKHTY3758sPqAUU3pw6m8JvmWQzO9sBLnqRsxUKW-ayN2qoUVYKM1uhm37XPA=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/wP7Hll5v4JkG9Yx91t8A0pGoz1wbJKdWl3M92dhPM9CMdF-_akiYWZVBaLA1SqzFQ8d3sw65mmPwPy-jK8fJ2hqIxiBf1bXjOdHXuV6JK8bAikkyUEF6_1BTZd45OcS05atsGgAiFw=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/OEBngfjcxmFqR_lxkt5beaWwZoHUc2OiEei_Kx7d9ZCR3RjQUZfr2pGMsuvRwKOiVTyxMYmpaQZnL90yRHW2K7DMrcTFVn3XI_vu_x6N9AHmnhFAUW44CyILj_jaWQGd_-Tuc8Lo3Q=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/K6ki8d0DUnqjM81A4DKmxroDgBhLTCvkqjNM9d-FuDh1sIKoc7Tg0DUP2LSLToXXVwd4On9lP5aewYvDFexOWh_w36ViVMPBy4a_BfpISDwYl10mvnlBYwhEGyaCXcS4OvgIQ_SRJw=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/q0eMcSq0N86KVHDd9HRBNFzblmX8Fq77-uhKJnClTd7fEvGozbQztgKn9FMUvKGHwv1DhLz2_0Bi5w7qPQqja9Bi9xfrvJ-Eg2WELOifqdDkMWCuMG9NGKtAwCSlTnWB38tgaHTilQ=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ocEey_fcol42_CR4XoCDJ6vMPKFW00nb8doIVjJ2GSE-grOjZwL026GWkWT9yGVvpwhy4i4C8Scg6x1NWuJKvzZJF_6vGZBPBgAV0xCPeDqmfOZdd86Wwi4boDoFBJsOfmfL3DOSmQ=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/wJmh9xRpfKnRRgQUGoHPZTwlAo9Nagmuh7LMuYLALNp6ltA3T7OaWrjCTx8mV012MryBZJ-_sBb-aecvfpUeZDELPVHGNnN4-52bwZzSLjcMqBcHqSnEsz_hobP9NimsWxblooxmgQ=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Dik1vkHNm7XZzV4dZCJI7uBOUzr3cQm9RfiEzOwYBMqy26kVitK2nePTqI0_iL_h1w5rA9TSxFjavjiypS6Wu5dcU5MDyTC8Z1Ecv_M__EDB_4v5xxrqhku4N678PvB_3P9Wbifqcg=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/J9lLLYULC_2hJPY0dKjtdYZabUAw9HbCfV023smdOYCQO3WcevDqPp9xfOgSVbXg0Th62SOdgWszfhJBHWG6u_M9L_IF4vbaQ4iiH0mbOABOrwEXhTD4KuaHYAZcpnRbFeWevu58yw=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/e216NxNB6I8a9qcjhxUXc7INo5hk-m6MHER9ml2zuG37L00DlibNreOJwLg2suJFh1zpNJn0fC8IYRyxkgirxA_vFUjiMjTcG3xW29vZ1v-Mi-m3dNpS_wK_XJi63ncNhkbrp2raBA=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KbA0w_-CJ9Rtzi4X3NXLCUJCtMGjG8F8eUB15MbIRpByjPhFWguyl3yPwTh3JJYsY5eeCWlMnhYUQ-v1_VN63KDT90A_dvMztRqPliPxepJFhOU6z9Na11OrXVxVyBBTKdzi30vF0A=w1920-h1080"></object>
</div>



    

  </div>
  <div class="galleryright" style="background-color:#000000;">
    <div class="acerill-custom-form" data-form-id="ca3d163c-517f-4dda-8e8c-202a1cb2e3dc"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://custom-forms-client.acerill.com/js/custom-forms-v2.js"></script>
  </div>
</div>

</div>

  
<style>
  
      .gallerycolumn {
  float: left;
}

.galleryleft {
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
}

.galleryright {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}
  

  
  
#image-gallery {
  border: 0px #555 solid;
  background-color: #ffffff;

  max-width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  
  
}
</style>



<style>

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*="galleryright"] {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  
  [class*="galleryleft"] {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  
}
  
</style>
```

I couldnt get the button to work in this website since, I dont know how to put it together since a lot of other codes within my store code are called and used to create the code. Also JS for the code is too large to place here. All I want to know is how to refresh webpage (all popup data) only when popup is opened, and whilst page is refreshing keep the popup open without closing it. I am sure this will be the fix to my issue but if there is another way to fix this please provide an answer. Your help is greatly appreciated

Kind Regards

Comment: Just recently found out about ajax code... trying to get it too work but am still unsuccessful. Im assuming ajax could be my solution

Comment: Ajax and JQuery or Ajax and JavaScript will help you refreshing your data in the page without refreshing the page itself, there is no way you can refresh a page and keep a popup opened because the popup is a part of the loaded page. what data you want to refresh on your page?

Comment: I'm not to sure, I just know that the only time my google photo gallery works is when the page is refreshed and the popup is opened before the page finishes loading. I'm assuming to just refresh the content within the popup.

Comment: ajax isnt the answer... im really lost. There not on the same domain. Im trying to connect to my google photos albums which are hosted on google photos. This embed works when its run directly on the page. Only time it fails is when its in a popup. Why would it fail in a popup and not just on the page. What is causing this error. do u know?

Comment: Never found an answer to this issue, but I found a solution by using a different site. Just make all your albums using this website and they work.

https://www.cincopa.com/